Question about proof that $\pi(x)$ is not rational

The prime number counting function $\pi(x)$ is not a rational function, i.e. there are no polynomials $P(X), Q(X) \in \mathbb{C}[X]$ with the properties $Q(n) \neq 0$ and
$$
\pi(n)=\frac{P(n)}{Q(n)} \quad \text { for all } \quad n \in \mathbb{N} .
$$

Proof. Suppose $\operatorname{deg}(P)=m$ and $\operatorname{deg}(Q)=n$, then $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\theta\left(x^{m-n}\right)$. Theorem 1 implies $\pi(x)$ cannot be asymptotic to $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ as
$$
\pi(x)=\theta\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right) \neq \theta\left(x^{m-n}\right) .
$$


Theorem 1. (Chebyshev) For every integer $n \geq 2$ we have
$$
\frac{1}{6} \frac{n}{\log n}<\pi(n)<6 \frac{n}{\log n} .
$$


My question: What does $\theta(x)$ mean here? Does it mean asymptotically equivalent? If so, isnt the theorem that actually gives this the prime number theorem?

@DietrichBurde That's probably not the meaning of $\theta$ here, because then the identity $\pi(x)=\theta\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right)$ used in the proof is false.

I think this is probably the Knuth notation: $f(x) = \theta(g(x))$ means $f(x)= O(g(x))$ and $g(x) = O(f(x))$, often written also as $f(x) \asymp g(x)$. That is, there exists constants $A,B$ such that $A f(x) \le g(x) \le B f(x)$.

Big Theta, in Knuth notation,  refers to simultaneous upper and lower bounds, see this.  Thus $f=\Theta(g)$ means that, for large $n$, we can find constants $c_1,c_2$ with $c_1\times g(n)<f(n)<c_2\times g(n)$, just as in the theorem you quote.

For an elementary proof of the result see this post, for example.

Not to quibble about premises, but the function $\pi(x)$ is usually understood to return the (integer) number of prime numbers which are $\le x$. When you evaluate $\pi(x)$ using various formulas to allow for a relatively accurate estimate of the number of prime numbers less than or equal to very large values of $x$, there may be no reason to expect that the returned value will be either integer or even rational. The fact that $\pi(x)$ cannot be represented as the ratio of polynomials seems unsurprising.

@DietrichBurde I like the proof you linked to, although there's an even easier one: if $\pi(x)$ is a rational function, then so is $\pi(x-1)$ and hence so is $\pi(x)-\pi(x-1)$. But $\pi(n)-\pi(n-1)=0$ for every composite integer $n$, and so this supposed rational function has infinitely many zeros, which means it's identically zero, which means $\pi(x)$ is constant—contradiction.
